# Different types of uncountability

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Do there exist different types of uncountability? I am well aware that $o(\aleph_0) < o (\mathbb{R}) < o (\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$, and so on.

I have looked around to no avail, however; is there a stricter definition for cardinality than "two cardinal numbers are the same if there exists a 1-1 correspondence between their sets"? That is, is there a rigorous definition for uncountability?

Comment: As long as the cardinality of a set is greater than $\aleph_0$, it's uncountable. So you've already named two "types" of uncountability.

Comment: That's precisely it, though, and it *is* rigorous. A set $A$ is countable iff there exists some injection $f:A\to\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: And why isn't that a rigorous definition of uncountability?

Answer (score 3):

The definition of countable is that there exists an injection from the set into $\Bbb N$. Being uncountable, if so, means  not being countable.

The analogy is with being infinite. Recall that infinite means "not finite", but it doesn't specify the actual cardinality.

Comment: +1 Sometimes I forget it's possible to explain things in plain English :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $c$ is any cardinal number, then $c < 2^c$.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for cardinality is correct. From this definition, the following definition for uncountability follows:

A set $S$ is uncountable if and only if,

$$\operatorname{card}(\mathbb{N})<\operatorname{card}(S)$$

Where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers, and $\operatorname{card}(\mathbb{N}):=\aleph_0$. As you stated, $\operatorname{card}(\mathbb{N})<\operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R})<\operatorname{card}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$, so $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ can be considered two different "types" of uncountability. That is, they are two uncountable sets with different cardinalities.

Comment: Do they possess any further properties, specific to themselves?

Comment: @MathApprentice That I'm not sure of, since I'm not aware of any algebraic structures built around a set with a cardinality of $\aleph_2$.

Comment: @Ataraxia: In many models of set theory $|\Bbb R|=\aleph_2$. In those I am sure that you can point at many, if not most, structures of this cardinality.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Really? My understanding was that $|\mathbb{R}|=\aleph_1$ and $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|=\aleph_2$. Are there structures with the same cardinality as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. $\aleph_1$ is the least uncountable cardinality. Whether or not $|\Bbb R|=\aleph_1$ is unprovable from the usual axioms of set theory, and it is known as the continuum hypothesis. There are set theoretic axioms which imply that $|\Bbb R|=\aleph_2$, they don't tell us much on $|\cal P(\Bbb R)|$, though -- that one is still *very* open for change between the models of set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was going by what the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number) says. I guess there are different conventions (the one from wikipedia and the one you stated).

Comment: @Ataraxia: No, there are no "different conventions". The aleph numbers have a very very concrete definition. If you read the article that you have linked more carefully you'll see that the assertion that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ is known as the continuum hypothesis, and that it is independent of the usual axioms of set theory (i.e. ZFC). In the definition of $\aleph_1$ (see section "Aleph-one") the term "real numbers" doesn't even appear, nor does the notation as $\Bbb R$. So I'm not sure how you concluded that $\aleph_1$ is defined as the cardinality of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay. I suppose I'll look into it more to see which convention is the more common one.

Comment: But there are no conventions in the definition of $\aleph$-numbers!